# Advice on refactoring recursive 2dtree contains method

Tags: java, recursion

I am taking the Coursera Algorithms course (which is excellent by the way) and I am implementing a 2DTree for one of the assignments. This tree inserts points into the tree but is different from a BST in that it alternates comparing the x-value and y-value to decide where to put the points in the tree. In any case, I would like a critique of my contains method. It works fine but I believe there is a gap in my knowledge that is preventing me from simplifying it. Specifically I am having to pass a boolean called ***found***. Is there a way to do this without having to do that in my code? Please critique anything you think might be helpful for my learning and development. Below is the relevant code

```
private enum Orientations {
    compareX, compareY,
}

public boolean contains(Point2D p) {
    checkForNullArgument(p);
    return contains(root, p, Orientations.compareX,false);
}            // does the set contain point p?

private boolean contains(Node node, Point2D point, Orientations orientation,boolean found) {
    if(node == null)
        return false;
    if (node.p.equals(point)) {
        StdOut.println("Found equal point");
        found = true;
        return found;
    }
    switch (orientation) {
        case compareX:
            Comparator<Point2D> cmpX = Point2D.X_ORDER;
            int compX = cmpX.compare(point, node.p);
            if (compX < 0) found = contains(node.left, point, Orientations.compareY,found);
            else if (compX >= 0) found = contains(node.right, point, Orientations.compareY,found);
            break;
        case compareY:
            Comparator<Point2D> cmpY = Point2D.Y_ORDER;
            int compY = cmpY.compare(point, node.p);
            if (compY < 0) found = contains(node.left, point, Orientations.compareX,found);
            else if (compY >= 0) found = contains(node.right, point, Orientations.compareX,found);
            break;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly don't need the found parameter. Get rid of it, and just add it inside your function, before the switch:

```
private boolean contains(Node node, Point2D point, Orientations orientation) {
  ...
  boolean found=false;
  ...
```